# How to write unit test cases like JUnit for a bean shell script

Tags: junit, testcase, beanshell, test-coverage

I have a Bean Shell script and I want to know how can I write test cases like JUnit?

Answer (score 1):

[Beanshell](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell) project is on github, you can see it's using [JUnit](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell/blob/master/src/test/java/bsh/BshMethodTest.java) for tests

For example

> ```
> @Test
> public void testHashCode_contract() {
>    final String name = "testMethod";
>    final BshMethod method1 = new BshMethod(name,
>          Integer.class, new String[0], new Class[0], new Modifiers[0], null, null, null);
>    final BshMethod method2 = new BshMethod(name,
>          Integer.class, new String[0], new Class[0], new Modifiers[0], null, null, null);    
>    Assert.assertTrue("precondition check for test failed.",
>          method2.equals(method1));
>    Assert.assertEquals("Equal classes should have equal hashcodes",
>          method2.hashCode(), method1.hashCode());
> }
> ```